# How to make Ulam number sequence in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure this problem out, I already checked my code but I don't know what the problem is.

This is the question: A mathematician Ulam proposed generating a sequence of numbers from any positive integer n (n>0) as follows.

```
    if n is 1, it will stop.
    if n is even, the next number is n/2.
    if n is odd, the next number is 3 * n + 1.
    continue with the process until reaching 1.
    here some examples for the first few integers.
    2->1
    3->10->5->16->8->4->2->1
    4->2->1
    6->3->10->5->16->8->4->2->1
    7->22->11->34->17->52->26->13->40->20->10->5->16->8->4->2->1
    Sample Run:
    Enter Positive Integer: 5
    The ulam Number Sequence is : 5->16->8->4->2->1
```

this is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ulam Number Sequence</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" onsubmit=" return false">
Enter positive integer: <input type="number" id="num" required>
<button onclick="process()">Process</button>
<button onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>
</form>
<p id = "info"> </p>
<script>


function isOdd(num) {
    var odd = true;
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
       if (num % i == 0) {
           odd = false;
           break;
       }
    }
    return odd;
  }
  function isEven(num) {
    var even = true;
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
       if (num % i == 1) {
           even = false;
           break;
       }
    }
    return even;
  }
function process(){
var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
var result1 = [];


for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++){

    if(isOdd(i)){
        result1[result1.length] = i /2;

    }
    if(isEven(i)){

        result1[result1.length] = 3 * i + 1;
    }

    if(isOdd(result1)){
        result1[result1.length] = result1 / 2;
    }
    if(isEven(result1)){

        result1[result1.length] = 3 * result1 +1;
    }

    //result1[result1.length] = i * 3 + 1;
   document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = result1.join("->");
    }
   }




   function Reset(){
   document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";
   document.getElementById("num").value = "" ; 
  }

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem you actually have?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to do ulam number sequence if you enter a positive integer in text box the process button generates the number sequence that you input if the number is reaches in 1 the programe will stop just like this enter number of positive integer: 5  the ulam number sequence is: 5->16->8->4->2->1 and im confuse to how to display the sequence of numbers...sorry

Comment: Edit your question and add that information into it.  it will help.

Comment: `document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = result1.join("->");` is in the for loop, it should be outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a solution for you (and a little hint):

```js
function process() {
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value),
        result = [n];

    if (isFinite(n) && n && n === Math.abs(n)) {
        while (n !== 1) {
            // basically this is all to do.
            n = n % 2 ? 3 * n + 1 : n / 2;
            result.push(n);
        }
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = result.join(' > ');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 'Does not compute!';
    }
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('num').value = ''
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onsubmit=" return false">
    Enter positive integer: <input type="number" id="num" required>
    <button onclick="process()">Process</button>
    <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
</form>
<p id="info"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Ms. ! but, what is isFinite function? what is the method inside in  isFinite? thank you again!

Comment: [`isfinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) is a function which checks for a finite number, [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) returns the absolute value, so the check allows only positive numbers to process.